# How is this string in an array represented in assembly when a C program is compiled using the gcc -S option?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

This is a C program, which has been compiled to assembly using `gcc -S`. How is string "Hello, world" represented in this program?

This is the C-code:

```
1.        #include <stdio.h>
2.        
3.        int main(void) {
4.        
5.            char st[] = "Hello, wolrd";
6.            printf("%s\n", st);
7.
8.            return 0;
9.       }
```

Heres the assembly code:

```
1.        .intel_syntax noprefix
2.        .text
3.        .globl  main
4.
5. main:
6.         push    rbp
7.         mov     rbp, rsp
8.         sub     rsp, 32
9.         mov     rax, QWORD PTR fs:40
10         mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax
11.        xor     eax, eax
12.        movabs  rax, 8583909746840200520
15.        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-32], rax
14.        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-24], 1684828783
15.        mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-20], 0
16.        lea     rax, [rbp-32]
17.        mov     rdi, rax
18.        call    puts
19.        mov     eax, 0
20.        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
21.        xor     rdx, QWORD PTR fs:40
22        je      .L3
22.        call    __stack_chk_fail
23.  .L3:
24.        leave
25.        ret
```

Comment: For completeness show also the C source code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using a local buffer in function `main`, initialized from a string literal.  The compiler compiles this initialization as setting the 16 bytes at `[rbp-32]` with 3 `mov` instructions.  The first one via `rax`, the second immediate as the value is 32 bits, the third for a single byte.

`8583909746840200520` in decimal is `0x77202c6f6c6c6548` in hex, corresponding to the bytes `"Hello, W"` in little endian order, `1684828783` is `0x646c726f`, the bytes `"orld"`. The third mov sets the final `'\0'` byte. Hence the buffer contains "Hello, World".

This string is then passed to `puts` for output to `stdout`.

Note that `gcc` optimized the call `printf("%s\n", "Hello, World");` to `puts("Hello, World");`!  By the way, `clang` performs the same optimization.

Comment: @Yeezus : If this answer solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer. More on how to accept and why, please see this SO information: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/271768

Comment: @chqrlie, if you could some how answer any future questions I might have, I'd greatly appreciate it...

Answer (score 2):

Interesting.

If you'd written `const char *str="..."`, gcc would have passed `puts` a pointer to the string sitting there in the `.rodata` section, like in [this godbolt link](http://goo.gl/Bcqkbf).  (Well-spotted by chqrlie that gcc is optimizing printf to puts).

Your code forces the compiler to make a writeable copy of the string literal, by assigning it to a non-const `char[]`.  (Actually, even with `const char str[]`, gcc still generates it on the fly from mov-immediates.  clang-3.7 [spots the chance to optimize](http://goo.gl/vCKNUo), though.)

Interestingly, it encodes it into immediate data, rather than copying into the buffer.  If the array had been global, it would have just been sitting there in the regular `.data` section, not `.rodata`.

---

Also, in general avoid using `main()` to see compiler optimization.  gcc on purpose marks it as "cold", and optimizes it less.  This is an advantage for real programs that do their real work in other functions.  No difference in this case, renaming main.  But usually if you're looking at how gcc optimizes something, it's best to write a function that takes some args, and use those.  Then you don't have to worry about gcc seeing that the inputs or loop-bounds are compile-time constants, either.

Comment: Your final synopsis on code optimisation is a going to come in handy. Thanks.

Comment: if you could some how answer any future questions I might have, I'd greatly appreciate it...

Comment: @Yeezus: I'd suggest reading http://agner.org/optimize/ if you're interested in optimizing asm, or C that turns into good asm.